# Vaadin 23 reduce buton width in the cell of FormLayout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin23

I added a `Button` component to the `FormLayout` cell. Now, the button takes full cell width. I need to reduce the button width to be sized like an Icon or a little bit bigger. I tried to set button width with `setWidth` method, but the button width doesn't react to this. How to properly reduce the button width in FormLayout cell and aligh it to the left side of the cell?
Right now I have the following:

[image]

but I need something like this:

[image]

Btw, are you able to access the demo examples on the following page https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/basic-layouts ? Right now, I may only see the code, but the actual examples don't show. They worked fine before.

Comment: This seems to be a performance issue and happens from time to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the FormLayout works.

You could wrap the button into a Span. Then the Span will have the width calculated by the FormLayout and the Button keeps the set width.